# AFNetworking 2.0 spring MVC upload file

Tags: ios, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data, afnetworking-2

I have a problem uploading a file to spring MVC service.
This is a Spring MVC @RequestBody for the service

```
@ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@PathVariable Integer something, @RequestParam String something, @RequestParam String something, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

And when I try uploading a file using AFNetworking 2.0

```
    [manager POST:requestUrl parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"file.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];

}
```

It doesn't recognize the file parameter at all and just returns invalid parameters error. I can not debug the service method..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, I just didn't pass the parameters (since our API has only @PathVariable, no @RequestParam):

```
NSString *urlString = @"your url";
NSData *fileData; // NSData of your image
NSString *fileName = @"fileName";

[manager POST:urlString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData name:@"file" fileName:fileName mimeType:@"image/png"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [delegate apiCall:API_FILE_UPLOAD finishedWithObject:responseObject];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [delegate apiCall:API_FILE_UPLOAD failedWithObject:error];
}];
```

I actually used your example, and passed nil for params :)